# Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise edition offline installation fails

Tags: windows, visual-studio, installation, offline

I have executed this command on online machine;

vs_enterprise.exe --layout c:\localVSlayout --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop --includeOptional --lang en-US

then copy folder to offline machine, and I have executed this command on offline machine;

c:\localVSlayout\vs_enterprise.exe --noWeb --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop --includeOptional

But I got this error message;
"An installation file didn't download .....payload.vsix"

I use this this website as reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022
After contacting with support, the only possible reason seems that different operating system versions are used for online (Windows 11) and offline (Windows 10) machines. Could it be reason?

Comment: HI Ali, any update of this issue, have you checked my answer, does it works? :)

Comment: No, it did not work.

Comment: Could you please share the entire error message? :)

Answer (score 0):

For your question,

1, I suggest you run this command to check whether there are some specific things not prepared(in your machine that have network.):

`vs_enterprise.exe --layout <layoutDir> --verify`

After that, run this command to fix:

`vs_enterprise.exe --layout <layoutDir> --fix`

2, Delete the old layout in offline machine.

3, Confirm the above command is success and copy the layout to the machine offline.

After the above steps, please check if the error is still the same.

Refer to this official document:

[Verify a layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#verify-a-layout)

[Fix a layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#fix-a-layout)